# How to store a large string value into CLOB object using stored procedure?

Tags: java, sql

I am getting a CSV file as a String value. Now I am passing this String as input to my stored procedure where it is stored as CLOB. When I am trying to do this, I get the following error : "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error".

Is there any way to convert String to CLOB before passing it to stored procedure?

Comment: `ORA-6502` might mean that your string is too long. The limit for binding strings from outside PL/SQL is 4000 chars, I think. I don't know much about Java, but in C#/.NET you may pass it as a stream, I think, or (even better) open a LOB locator on the DB side and pass your string data to the DB in chunks. For more precise info you'll have to refer to your Java documentation and to your local Oracle DB expert.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the reply.
I thought of using CLOB for this, but how can I convert my String to CLOB? Is there any way to achieve this through JAVA?

Comment: Yes, there is ... Passing the CLOB value to Oracle as CLOB value, not as a string value. Search your Java classes documentation for info on how to do that.

Comment: If this answer is not enough for you, then post the Java code snippet for loading your CSV file into your question, then I (or anyone, for that matter) might be able to help you.

Comment: Nevermind, this got fixed, thanks to you.